# Can you install delayed signed assembly in GAC? CLR via C# 4th Edition

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, gac, strongname

I was reading `CLR via c# (Fourth Edition)` and in chapter 3 about strong named assembly author says:

> When the compiler or AL.exe detects that you’re delay signing an
>   assembly, it will emit the assembly’s AssemblyDef manifest entry,
>   which will contain the assembly’s public key. Again, the presence of
>   the public key allows the assembly to be placed in the GAC. It also
>   allows you to build other assemblies that reference this assembly; the
>   referencing assemblies will have the correct public key in their
>   AssemblyRef metadata table entries. When creating the resulting
>   assembly, space is left in the resulting PE file for the RSA digital
>   signature. (The utility can determine how much space is necessary from
>   the size of the public key.) Note that the file’s contents won’t be
>   hashed at this time either.
>
> At this point, the resulting assembly doesn’t have a valid signature.
>   Attempting to install the assembly into the GAC will fail because a
>   hash of the file’s contents hasn’t been done—the file appears to have
>   been tampered with.

As you can see, in the first paragraph, he says, when we use /delaysign the assemlby's manifest will contain the `public key` which will aloow it be installed in `GAC`. But in the second paragraph, he says, since the file is not *yet* singed with private key, attempting to install it into `GAC` would fail. So, what is it? Can you install it or not?

Comment: "it will emit the assembly’s
AssemblyDef manifest entry, which will contain the assembly’s public key".  it means the entry is emitted.

Comment: @Dowvoter: Care to at least comment why the downvote?

Comment: @Matt Well I know entry is emiited, I checked the assembly manifest by ildasm and the public key was there. But it was not my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It will **not** be able installed in `GAC`. I delay singed an assembly and tried to install in `GAC`, and I got this error message

```
Failure adding assembly to the cache: Strong name signature could not be verified. Was the assembly build delay-signed?
```

( Just in case someone is here wondering the same ). You can skip the hash check by

`SN -Vr assembly.dll`

and then you can install it in `GAC` and then to rehash (or rather hash) you can do this,

`SN.exe -Ra assembly.dll yourStrongNameKey.PrivateKey`

The only thing I am still wondering is that how can you extract this private key from .snk file, there seems to be no way to do that.

Comment: Usually the snk file you generated contains the public and private key. With sn.exe -p you can extract the public key when you want your developers delay sign without having access to the private key.

Comment: @LarsTruijens Yeah, I know you can use -p key to extract the public key, but when you sign/hash again after delay signing you have to sign with private key, right? Using the switch -Ra? But where the H*ll would you get the private key from?

Comment: You should have the private key. You got it when you generated the key. Just supply the snk file you got from doing sn.exe -k. It contains the private key as well as the public key in one file.