# install System.Diagnostics.Debug into Mono-GAC

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, mono

I try to use `foo.dll` and this dll uses `Debug.WriteLine` from `System.Diagnostics.Debug`. Unfortunately `System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll` is not preinstalled in the GAC of mono (`gacutil -l | grep System\.Diagnostics`). Therefor i installed it via:

```
nuget install System.Diagnostics.Debug

Feeds used:
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installing package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug' to '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0/ref/netcore50'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/system.diagnostics.debug/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/system.diagnostics.debug/index.json 129ms


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0' with respect to project '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0/ref/netcore50', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Gathering dependency information took 24.11 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0'
Retrieving package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.3.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Adding package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0' to folder '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0/ref/netcore50'
Added package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0' to folder '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0/ref/netcore50'
Successfully installed 'System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.3.0' to /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0/ref/netcore50
Executing nuget actions took 208.36 ms
```

The installation step afterwards failed with this message:

```
gacutil -i System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
Failure adding assembly System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll to the cache: Strong name cannot be verified for delay-signed assembly
```

I am new to `C#`, `mono`, `gacutil` etc... i am not sure how to bypass the verification.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039728/9363973) help? Also, are you working on a pre-existing application or just learning on a small application?

Comment: no, the option `-Vr` is not available for `sn` under linux. I am working on a pre-existing application which i want to include in a python application with pythonnet.

Comment: If you are really new, please skip Mono and use .NET Core directly, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/